# Populate TextBox based on DateTime Field. ASP.NET C# JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Ok so I have a StartDate field:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtnewStartDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StartDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")%>'
                    CssClass="datepicker grid_5 text"></asp:TextBox>
```

I also have a TextBox which I would like to be auto filled based on the StartDate.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateBatch" Text='<%# Bind("DateBatch") %>' runat="server" CssClass="text"></asp:TextBox>
```

So for example the StartDate field will look like: **9/1/2015** (After a user has selected a date from the date box)

Now based on the date someone selected in this field the DateBatch field will look like: **Batch-912015**

I have seen an example using javascript but im not sure how to call the variables from javascript to asp or c#.

Javascript Ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function autoBatch() {
        value1 = $('#StartDate').val();
        var batch = "Batch-" + value1;
    }
</script>
```

Please let me know if I was not informative enough or anyone needs more info thanks! I don't need to use javascript whatever method works I would just like to understand how to do this from start to finish mainly confused on how to complete this fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an OnTextChanged event to the textbox, as below....

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtnewStartDate" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtnewStartDate_TextChanged" Text='<%# Bind("StartDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")%>' CssClass="datepicker grid_5 text"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then in your code behind, catch the value and update your DateBatch, as below....

```
protected void txtnewStartDate_TextChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {

     txtDateBatch.Text = txtnewStartDate.Text

    }
```

Or with your batch code added.....

```
protected void txtnewStartDate_TextChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {

     txtDateBatch.Text = "Batch-" & txtnewStartDate.Text.replace('/','')

    }
```

Something like that.

Comment: I would use `string.Format` (a personal preference).  Also, this would require a server-side Postback.  In theory, your solution will work, but if a Postback is expensive and he truly wants a client-side solution, this will not work.